# error: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xd8 (...): ordinal not in range(...) What am I doing wrong

Tags: python, unicode, encoding, ascii, decoding

What is wrong with this python asciicode:

```
with open('poetry.txt', 'w',encoding="utf-8") as outfile:
    for fname in poem_txt_list:
        with open(fname) as infile:
            outfile.write(infile.read())
```

it gives me the error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnicodeDecodeError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-51-dc1d05741086> in <module>
      2     for fname in poem_txt_list:
      3         with open(fname) as infile:
----> 4             outfile.write(infile.read())

/opt/anaconda3/envs/MLinPractice/lib/python3.6/encodings/ascii.py in decode(self, input, final)
     24 class IncrementalDecoder(codecs.IncrementalDecoder):
     25     def decode(self, input, final=False):
---> 26         return codecs.ascii_decode(input, self.errors)[0]
     27 
     28 class StreamWriter(Codec,codecs.StreamWriter):

UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xd8 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I am doing something very fundamentally wrong I think. The original code from the github which I'm trying to adjust is the following:

```
#get list of text files in data
poem_txt_list = glob.glob('data/*.txt')

with open('raw_corpus.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    for fname in poem_txt_list:
        with open(fname) as infile:
            outfile.write(infile.read())

data_dir = 'raw_corpus.txt'
text = helper.load_data(data_dir)
```

I have one file ("poetry.txt", UTF-8 encoded) which I want to place in the code instead of "raw_corpus.txt". I think its the right spot for my file to go but I am not entirely sure. I also don't have a list of data, I only have one txt file with all the poetry as one long text. Do I even need the first line?

Comment: It would help if you gave the full stack trace so we could see where the error occurred.

Comment: okay, I added it!

Comment: What @MarkRansom said... On a side note - I'd change your write operation to be `outfile.writelines(infile)`

Comment: What encodings have you tried for the `infile` ?

Comment: @JonClements so I just tried the encoding="utf-8" for the infile and that seemed to work! thats great but apparently the "poetry.txt" file is still not "utf-8" in the next code cell? thanks so so much :)

Comment: If you open "poetry.txt" for writing with the "w" mode, you define it's encoding. With your code, the written file will be encoded with UTF-8. Note: if you get a "decode" error, then usually there's something wrong with reading. An "encode" error (`UnicodeEncodeError`) points to problems with writing.

Comment: What do you mean by *'apparently the "poetry.txt" file is still not "utf-8" in the next code cell'*? Please make a [mre].